# Adding the total of two SUM functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I do to sum the result of this queries using postgresql?:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM credit_balance

SELECT SUM(value) FROM debit_balance
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT SUM(value) FROM credit_balance UNION ALL SELECT SUM(value) FROM debit_balance)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(value) FROM credit_balance) + (SELECT SUM(value) FROM debit_balance)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the field name after sum. you can write your query using union all as following:

```
select sum(val_sum) from (SELECT SUM(value) as val_sum FROM credit_balance UNION ALL SELECT SUM(value) as val_sum FROM debit_balance) as united_table;
```

OR

```
select sum(value) from (SELECT value FROM credit_balance UNION ALL SELECT value FROM debit_balance) as united_table.
```